# Connect WCF Based Web service application to TCP server Listener

Tags: .net, sockets, wcf, tcpclient, webservice-client

Hi to all experts in StackOverflow ,
I want to connect a WCF based application to a TCP listener , my solution is to use TcpClient class , Do you think this is right or WCF can handle this situation with another approach?

Best regards.